# How can I scroll left and right in Eclipse editor with the keyboard without moving the cursor?

Tags: eclipse, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

To scroll within the *Eclipse* editor without moving the cursor up and down one can use *CTRL+Down* or *CTRL+Up*. But what about ***left*** and ***right***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. If you search **keys** in Eclipse's **Preferences**, you will find out that you only have `Scroll up` and `Scroll down` that you can set hotkeys on.

My recommendation would be changing the maximum line length in the editor. 
Make your code shorter. After all, looooong lines of code are not so readable.

Also, resize your editor area. If you feel strangled, remove the `Outline`, `TaskList`, and `Build` view from your right side of Eclipse, and enlarge the editor.

Answer (score 0):

New version of Eclipse is available to use Horizontal scrolling with the scrollwheel.