# Eclipse horizontal scrolling keyboard shortcut

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut for horizontal scrolling in different views. This can be useful, for example, when used in the JUnit view to scroll it horizontally to the left / right in order to be able to read, in ease, the stack trace—if there's a test error.

Comment: In Linux this could be done outside Eclipse using key binding using `xbindkeys`. This example [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/404737/84445) shows how to do this for Shift+Mouse Scroll. You can replace the Mouse scroll in given example with some other keyboard key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I scroll left and right in Eclipse editor with the keyboard without moving the cursor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460005/how-can-i-scroll-left-and-right-in-eclipse-editor-with-the-keyboard-without-movi)

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it is not possible. Go to Window --> Preferences --> General --> Keys in eclipse. As you can see, you only have Scroll up and Scroll down that you can set hotkeys on. But not scroll left or scroll right.

Answer (score -2):

- Next View - ctrl+F7
- Previous View - ctrl+shift+F7

Comment: I'm not talking about switching from view to other. I'm talking about horizontal scrolling in the same view. If a view has a layout in such a way it has an horizontal scrollbar, then you can scroll that bar using the mouse. I'm wondering about doing the same thing but using the keyboard.